# Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean]

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I'm following along with [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9244FjHT2M) tutorial to work with [Apache Tiles 3](https://tiles.apache.org/) my projects servlet-context.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd        
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="ali.arshad.soomro" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"> 
    <property name="definitions"> 
    <list> 
    <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>        
    </list> 
    </property> 
</bean> 
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"> 
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" 
    /> </bean>
</beans:beans>
```

here I'm facing error

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>       - Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean] Offending resource: file [G:/Spring/java-blog/src/main/webapp/
>        WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
>       - Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [bean]
>       - cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.

at line `class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"` 
and error

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.

at line `class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"`.

pom.xml dependencies are

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId> 
    <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId> 
        <version>3.0.3</version> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId> 
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId> 
        <version>3.0.3</version> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId> 
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId> 
        <version>3.0.3</version> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId> 
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId> 
        <version>3.0.3</version> 
    </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId> 
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId> 
        <version>3.0.3</version> 
    </dependency>
```

**UPDATE**
after suggestion in Answer below I have made change in servlet-contex.xml as

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver">
<beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"></beans:property>
<beans:property name="order" value="0"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer" id="tilesConfigurer">
 <beans:property name="definitions" value="/WEB-INF/spring/tiles.xml"> </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Now I get this error

> Attribute : class
>   The fully qualified name of the bean's class, except if it serves only as a parent definition for child 
>    bean definitions.
>
> Data Type : string

at line `class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver"`
and at line `class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer"`
Please can any one suggest me a solution to these errors?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with namespace. You should have all tags starting with beans

Comment: The place where you are having this code, class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer", you need to use beans:bean instead of just bean. The entire xml will be evaluated based on the name space definitions given at the start of the xml

Comment: Looks like the class definition is not able to be resolved. Have you added the spring dependencies in pom.xml. I am not able to see them in your pom above

Comment: Using <beans:bean> is solving the problem